# How to fix Visual Studio 2012 freeze while editing aspx pages with installed Office Developer Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ms-office

I'm working with SharePoint 2013, so I need the Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 to be installed. When I'm editing .aspx pages associated with a Web Part, the Visual Studio is freezing for a few seconds every one or two minutes. How can I fix this problem?

**PS:**
I can change a default editor, assotiated with aspx pages, but I don't like this solution since I want to save intellisence and syntax highlight.

Comment: Can you be more specific, last time I used same combination was not having problem, until I reload/reopen the file from solution explorer. Make sure you are not having "Submit User Experience" "Enabled" If you have noticed, also in the bottom, help, disable the search solution online(if enables). Yes, the new visual studio works slow with HTML/ASPX page when you are in code editing mode, may be due to its improved schema checking mechanism.

Comment: How can I check, that "Submit User Experience" option is disabled?

Comment: When you start Visual studio, you will see one ICON( of visual studio) in the System TRAY in right bottom, look there >> you will click there and select no, else in past if you have selected yes, you may search in options/tools I am not sure ABOUT this if you have done yes in past

Comment: I have only "Updates" VS2012 ICON in the System Tray, nothing about User Experience Program. @MarmiK, are you sure, that you have installed Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 and you have no bugs with freezing aspx?

Comment: yes if you have web parts/components that you are importing, that will slow down while loading the design view. but no idea about proper relation with office developer tools, Yes I had installed them for excel operations using Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't use a design view for aspx pages. The bug looks like a VS is trying to request resources but has no permissions or resources are absent, so it waits for a minute, after that a timeout exception is occurring and then VS is continue working.

Comment: VS2012 Update 2 supposedly fixed a similar issue for WPF. Have you installed that update?

Comment: Yes, I have installed all updates, but the issue is still here.

Answer (score 1):

One tool you could use to diagnose this is SysInternal's **[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)**.  I've done this with periodic hang-ups in the past.  Start by just filtering **file and/or registry** operations on the Visual Studio process, devenv.exe.  Look for the last few to occur just before a hang-up, and use that data to further refine your filtering and searching.  Based on the periodic nature of the delay, my intuition says it's related to **background compilation** (i.e., the Intellisense database being updated).  So, you might want to filter further on **NCB** file ops, etc.